# group expression in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I've a report which has a has 5 columns on each page and I have a group defined which shows columns related to

A | B | C | D | E -  main column

X | Y | Z - group - A is the key

I have my query ORDER BY A, but when it is displayed it doesn't print the results in next page if A is changed.

Following is how I have a group defined.

```
<group name="A" isResetPageNumber="true" >
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{A}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band/>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

does A need to be part of the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. I had to add A with X, Y, and Z in order for group to work.

Comment: actually I was wrong, it's still a problem. I thought I fixed it by adding the columns but it still mixes up the results and never create a new page for it when A is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<group name="A" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" 
       isResetPageNumber="false" >
```